# selecting million rows is slow even for simple select statement

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, partitioning

I have simple table with partition(range partition 10 in number)

```
CREATE TABLE `document_key_points` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key_point_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_decimal` decimal(22,6) DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `data_boolean` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `document_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_integer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `data_string` text,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`key_point_id`),
  KEY `data_integer` (`data_integer`),
  KEY `document_id` (`document_id`),
  KEY `key_point_id` (`key_point_id`),
  KEY `data_boolean` (`data_boolean`),
  KEY `data_decimal` (`data_decimal`),
  KEY `data_date` (`data_date`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY RANGE (key_point_id) (
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (163),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (271),
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (364),
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (370), 
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (378),
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (384), 
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (397),
 PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (460), 
 PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (487),
 PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
```

I am running a simple select query and it is taking lot of time(12 sec) to execute

```
select data_string,document_id from document_key_points cd where key_point_id =12
```

**Explain**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cd    | ref  | key_pt_id     | key_pt_id| 4       | const | 1957136 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

I have 50 million rows in this table and the aim is to optimize the query  output close to 1-2 secs,
what approach will help me to optimize this query to reach 1-2 secs?

NOTE:same query is running in 8 sec without partitioning.

UPDATE:
Adding explain partitions

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cd    | p0         | ref  | key_pt_id     | key_pt_id | 4       | const | 1957136 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Is this on a current version of MySQL, like 5.6?

Comment: Please explain why you are partitioning this table.  Is there something driving it besides your attempt to optimize queries? What's the max length of the data you're storing in your `data_string` column? How many rows does this query return?

Comment: @tadman ya I am using MySql 5.6

Comment: @OllieJones only reason I am going ahead with partition is to optimize queries but not only for the query mentioned above,there are few more similar queries.max length of data I have in `data_string` is 1000 char (I have plans to change column type from text to varchar but will that help in considerable performance gain ?).this query is pulling close to million rows (920840)

Comment: It seems that your query is pulling a GiB or so of data. That's a lot of bits to process in around ten seconds. Is there a way to handle this sort of query without transporting your `data_string` values? I ask because queries like this can often be optimized with *compound covering indexes.*  Also, **it is unlikely that partitioning will help query performance on this table.**

Comment: Read this: http://www.slideshare.net/andrewtibets/my-sql-practicalpartitioning

Comment: @OllieJones `data_string` and `document_id` is a mandatory field in select,so your point is that there is no way we can query a text or varchar field with large number of row(> 1 million rows) in a few seconds or is there any other approach I can take ? my primary requirement is to query and select million + rows with `data_string` field ?

Comment: You can perhaps improve things a bit by changing the `key_point_id` index to (`key_point_id, is_deleted`). But I think the best thing to do would be to look into *what you need that million rows for*. I don't think you're displaying it in a single whoop. Whatever it is, could it perhaps be paged? If so, could data_string be retrieved later? Etc.

Comment: @lserni actual I already started looking into the solution you mentioned and I accept its a right approach, I don't need to mess with million rows in UI ,but before I give up on the above approach I just want to understand querying a table with text or varchar select field with more than million records in few secs is not possible ?

Comment: You need hardware capable of managing 1GB in those few seconds. Not the easiest thing. that.

Comment: Returning a one-gigabyte result set with more than a million rows in a few seconds is barely possible on an otherwise unloaded server. If you have other stuff going on in the server, it will become impossible unless you're willing to spend hundreds of thousands of dollars on hardware and tuning.  In any case, you should do a systems analysis to figure out what you are doing with a couple of million `data_string` items in ten seconds. That's a **lot** of data.

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The EXPLAIN says that the SELECT will return about 2 million rows.  That takes time, probably mostly I/O.  You should not expect sub-second response for such a large result set.

If your 'real' query was something else, then let's see it.  And show us `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...`, to confirm that "partition pruning" is working as expected.

Here's how your query should work:

1. Since the WHERE clause has a restriction on the PARTITION key (key_point_id =12), pruning should occur.
2. Now only partition p0 need be looked at.  That partition has millions of rows, correct?
3. Next some INDEX is used to finish the query; the optimizer picked key_point_id because of key_point_id=12.  And it apparently discovered about 2M rows have a value of 12, but that is a small enough fraction of p0 to be worth using the index.
4. So, we are not finished yet.  The index is scanned for all key_point_id=12 entries.  This is a linear ("range") scan of the index.
5. For each entry, it has to reach into the data BTree using the PRIMARY KEY to get the fields asked for by SELECT.  This is InnoDB, so the rest of the PK was also in the secondary key.  That's 2M probes based on (id, key_point_id) to find the desired data.

Note, that without partitioning (but with essentially the same indexes), steps 3-5 would explain the processing.  Only the trivial steps 1 & 2 would be removed.  PARTITIONing gave you no performance gain.

However, you saw a performance difference.  Did you run the query twice?  Did you run it on a cold system?  I suspect the difference you saw as almost entirely due to a difference in what happened to be cached at the time you ran them.

The partitioning you have is useful only(?) for queries like these:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (key_point_id = ...) AND something else indexed
SELECT ... WHERE (key_point_id BETWEEN..AND..) AND something else indexed
```

On a side note: KEY `data_boolean` (`data_boolean`), is probably never used -- Indexing flags by themselves are not worth it.

Since you have more fields, the answer changes.

First, note that `!=NULL` is *wrong*:

```
mysql> SELECT NULL != NULL, 'abc' != NULL, NULL IS NOT NULL, 'abc' IS NOT NULL;
+--------------+---------------+------------------+-------------------+
| NULL != NULL | 'abc' != NULL | NULL IS NOT NULL | 'abc' IS NOT NULL |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+-------------------+
|         NULL |          NULL |                0 |                 1 |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

That is, when testing, only 'abc' will be treated as not null.  NULL, itself will fail the test, hence be considered as NULL.

Secondly, flags and "!=" are killers for any attempt at optimization.  Can they at least be turned into "=" or "IS NULL"?

Comment: original  query had two more conditions `data_string !=null and is_deleted !=1` ,I have updated the explain partition in question, p0 has 4 million rows,I  warmed up the cache enough before taking the stats, also I doing this partition stuff just to optimize the query is there a better approach I can take ?

Comment: As everyone says, fetching 2M rows takes time.  It cannot be optimized without having magically faster disks and CPUs.

Answer (score -1):

I have created the same table but without partitions.I have generated some data. Around 10M rows. On my data it takes around 25 sec to perform your select.

If I change primary key just to id and disable usage of index key_point_id this select executed in 8 sec. So it's 3x faster.

```
ALTER TABLE document_key_points DROP primary KEY, ADD primary KEY(id);
SELECT data_string,document_id FROM document_key_points USE INDEX () WHERE key_point_id = 9;
```

I have done some more tests. I have created table with partitions. It does not matter how many records I have in the table. The only question is how many records in 1 partition.

So if I have 1-2 million rows in 1 partition I can extract 1 million rows in less then 2 sec. If I disable index I can extract data in 0.8 sec.

With 3-5 million records in 1 partition I can load data in around 4 sec with index and 2 sec if I don't use index.

I suggest to create more partitions and remove index key_point_id as for me it looks completely useless. In all my tests queries running at least 2x faster without index.

Comment: In my original table I have 57 million rows and I was able to optimize above query only till 8.51 sec(which pulls close of 1 million rows) using covering index

Comment: I'll try tomorow with 50million. But the thing is if you need to extract almast all data from the table (in your case 1\50) then index will just slow it down.

Comment: I have done some more test with randomly generated data. See my updated answer.

Comment: your stats are interesting that to wrt index,take away point: after partition always revisit on the your indexes.Thanks for the update.

Comment: There is another dimension to take into account:  Partition vs not; INDEX(key_point_id) or not; and what % of the partition (or table, if not partitioned) contains the desired key_point_id.  If the partition contains a significant percentage of that row, it will do a table scan instead of using the index.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of in benchmarking like this -- The first time you run a query, it is slow because of loading blocks from disk.  The second time will be faster.  Also, if you run a _different_ query second, it may be taking advantage of caching, hence be faster.  Run each query twice and take the second time.